# how can we add subdomain dynamicllay using vhost and nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, subdomain, vhosts

I want to create a subdomain as per the users username for every user's username is unique

I create subdomain manually but I don't know how to create it by users username

```
const subdomain = express();

const domain = "localhost";

  app.use(vhost(`username.${domain}`, subdomain)); //here username is manually i entered
```

how can we have done it by using an API to get the username from DB and create the subdomain

Comment: can anyone please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [node-awesome-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-awesome-router)
Here is example ho to configure routes with subdomains without any oder( hosts, nginx, etc..) settings

```
const router = NodeAwesomeRouter({
   app,
     routes: [{
        key: '/path',
        routes: {'/r1': ()=>{}, '/r2': () => {}, ...  },
        subdomain: 'users' // user.domain.com
      }, {
       key: '/path2',
       routes: {'/r1': ()=>{}, '/r2': () => {}, ...  },
       subdomain: 'dev' // dev.domain.com
      }], 
  })
```

Comment: i didint understand your comment

Comment: You can do somethink like . 
const subdomains = await dbSubdomainsSchema.findAll()
const routes = [];
subdomains.map(subdomain => {
    rotes.push({
          key: '/', 
          routes: {  }, 
          subdomain,
     })
})
NodeAwesomeRouter(app, routes)

Comment: Thanks , its not working for me